# Modern .Net in-memory Image representation

Tags: .net, image, image-processing

What would be the best built-in .Net 4.5 or newer class to hold a photo in-memory. 
My little project is a command-line program that will do image upload to a server. No image manipulations are planned. But data type should allow access to image dimensions.

Comment: A little more detail about where you get the image would be useful, but perhaps you're looking for [System.Drawing.Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: The program must be simple as possible: 
1. Load image from file
2. Upload to Flickr or similar
Must be in C# .Net

Comment: In that case, `Image` sounds like what you'd want! I'll answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It allows access to the dimensions of the image through it's `Height` and `Width` properties, and you can get it from a file via [`Image.FromFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).